# Styling of selectlist items in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, styling

I'm in the process of altering some code that I didn't wrote, AND I'm rather new to Razor

It is a select list of vehicles and the code looks like this:

```
<select name="selectVehicle" class="cls_vehicles" data-bind="options:        $root.vehicles,optionsCaption:$root.noVehicleText, optionsText:     'VehicleNumber',optionsValue: 'VehicleID',value: VehicleID"><option value=""/></select>
```

My datasource contains besides Vehicleid and Vehiclenumber also a Vehicletype, and now I want to highlight the vehicles according to type, so the gasoline vehicles is blue and the diesel ones are green.

But I have no idea of how to go about this, any help is very appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that data-bind tag is from Knockout? You don't have a tag for it, but that's where its pulling the options from. Do you want the solution in Razor, or Knockout? Using razor will require you to remove the knockout binding.

Answer (score 1):

So, your question code has a knockout data-binding for the options in it, so I am going to assume for now that you are using Knockout as the datasource. To do this, you will have to expand the binding a little, so that you can place a css-class on each option individually.

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedCar, foreach: cars">
    <option data-bind="css: { carDiesel: isDiesel, carGas: isGas }, text: name"></option>
</select>​
```

Now, this depends on the structure of your knockout viewmodel, but [here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/wTLMq/) I made using this method. You should be able to adapt it to fit yours. If you want a Razor-only solution, let me know.

Comment: Thank you, I entirely forgot to follow up on this. Yes you where correct, it was using Knockout. I was not aware of knockout's existence so it was a huge help to understand the code.